# Atom - проблема с кирилицей

Tags: windows, atom

Можно ли как то в Atom добавить кириллические символы, чтобы не было этой каши(плагин "Script")
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: python какой версии?

Comment: Python ver 3.7.0